# Connect:Direct(NDM) Support in Apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel, connect-direct

I have a requirement in my application to send data via FTP, SFTP, Email, MQ and Connect:Direct. I found Apache Camel was a good choice since it supports many protocols out of the box.

However, I have checked the apache camel documentation and could not find any component for file transfer via Connect:Direct (NDM). Does anyone knows if this is supported by Apache Camel ?

Comment: This is a list of official [Apache Camel components](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/index.html). Unfortunately `Connect:Direct` is not one of them. There doesn't seem to be a third party maintained component either. If you're interested in building one, [this guide](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/writing-components.html) may come handy

Comment: thank you @ShellDragon . This guide will be very helpful.